# Auto format with specific indentation/alignment C/C++ in vscode

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

So I am working on a school project in `C` using vscode. One of the most important things that we're thoroughly graded against is neat code formatting. Say I have declared 3 variables like this

```
int     i;
char    *s;
size_t  t;
```

they must be aligned exactly like this. Now enabling the vscode `"editor.formatOnSave": true` in the settings/settings.json`
 changes this to

```
int i;
char *s;
size_t t;
```

now is the a way in vscode to keep these variables aligned in a specific way like the first snippet or have the alignment done automatically?

Comment: a pity that you have to use a non-sense formattting. Note that what you have to write is bad because imagine you have to add a line `some_type_with_long_name x;` then you have to modify all lines above, this is a major annoyance in version control. Also `char  *s;` should rather be `char* s;` (however, thats slightly opinion based)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I know but  we're are required to else we're graded with a 0.

Comment: in VSCode, there are some plugins such as `beautify` to help you align for example on the `=` sign, or space . You just need to know how to configure it

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818, That issue of `char* s` or `char *s`, as you said, is opinion based but I have decided to keep the second notation just to specify that the type is `char` and not `char*`, just in case you would like to have multiple declarations on the same line

Comment: Well actually the type is `char *` LOL

Comment: @PhoenixBlue the more common approach is to have only one variable declaration per line. And yes, the type is `char*` not `char`, thats exactly the rationale for writing `char* s;` instead of `char *s;`  the `*` is part of the type, not part of the variable name

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 that depends on the language.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I was considering to complain about double tagging, but then remembered that often IDEs have options for "C/C++". Sorry for going a bit offtopic in the comments, lets just leave it at: it depends ;)

Comment: I'd say that in any way, it is imperative to work with the tools rather than against them. From that point of view, I'd expect your teacher to provide the pupils with such tools. Therefore: Have you asked your teacher about this? Hopefully, he doesn't expect you to use a text editor or the like and do it manually. I mean, it is a very good idea to ask this here, shows initiative and such, just saying that the teacher should be active here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the C/C++ extension you can configure the formater. Use `AlignConsecutiveDeclarations` from [clang-format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) to align variables like that.

Example of configuration (for `C_Cpp.clang_format_style`):

```
{ BasedOnStyle: LLVM, AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true }
```

So in your `settings.json` you can have something like this:

```
{
  "C_Cpp.clang_format_style": "{ BasedOnStyle: LLVM, AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true }",
}
```

Comment: Now how do I set it up in the C/C++ extension?

Comment: I edited my answer with an example, you just have to access the vscode configuration file

Comment: People may also be interested in `AlignConsecutiveAssignments: true`. This aligns at the equal sign for assignments.